# cannot find symbol method isSuccess() retrofit

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

When I updated to `retrofit:2.0.0` from beta4 I got this error:

> cannot find symbol method isSuccess()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a small problem the method `isSuccess()`  just become `isSuccessful()` and they both have the same functionality.
so just replace every `isSuccess()`  to `isSuccessful()`.